# How to pass extra keys in options to react-dropdown and get them back from the onChange prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am using this dropdown library [react-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown)

```js
export const currencies = [
    { value: 'USD', label: '$ USD', currencySign: "$" },
    { value: 'INR', label: '₹ INR', currencySign: "₹" },
    { value: 'CAD', label: 'C$ CAD', currencySign: "C$"  }
]


<Dropdown 
    options={currencies}
    onChange={newSelectedOption => console.log(newSelectedOption)} // Getting an object with only 2 keys: "label" & "value". The third key "currencySign" is not there!
/>
```

Is there any way I can get that "currencySign" in that onChange object?

Thanks!

Oct 13 2020 Update: Seems like the react-dropdown library doesn't provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `react-dropdown` library doesn't seem to bring that feature but you could do the following in your `onChange` function:

```
const selectedCurrency = currencies.find({value, label} => value === newSelectedOption.value && label === newSelectedOption.label)
```

And then you could retrieve the `currencySign` property

Answer (score 0):

You could write an helper function if you have access to the options array in your handler

```
Dropdown 
    options={currencies}
    onChange={onChange}
/>

onChange(selected){
  var itemWithCurrency = this.findSelected(selected.value,  this.currencies)
}

findSelected(value, items){
  return items.find(item => item.value === value)
}
```

Comment: I thought of this solution but unfortunately, it will complex the code. The prop given byy onChange is used in many places /: Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: You could also create a wrapper component for the drop down then add the logic above. Make the wrapper component pass the full object to onChange handler.